# Manage multi-level Ionic ionSideMenus

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to manage a SideMenu (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/) with multi-level hierarchy. A nice solution can be use multiple views to manage with `$stateProvider.state` and change the content change the content inside of `<ion-side-menu>`, but I do not know how to do.

`Option A
 |_ Sub-option 1
 |_ Sub-option 2
Option B
 |_ Sub-option 1`

Comment: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz

Comment: This is a solution to be taken into account. Thank you :)

Comment: have you ever used ng-switch? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: @JessPatton Thank you, I used this method. I'm very noob with AngularJS!